# How can i export my void update transform variables to a json file

Tags: c#, json, parsing, rotation

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using System.IO;
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour {
public Character player = new Character(0, 0, 0, 0,0);
    // Use this for initialization
    JsonData playerJson;
```

i want to be able to change the values from a json file of the rotating obstracles that i will add to my game but i cant possibly find a way to do this since i am very new to json files,so how can i add the values of the public class character within the void update or at least a way to just parse the variables for the rotation.

In more detail and in simpler words the void update is supposed to rotate the object as in the values you see inside but i want to export these values to a json file and for them to be changable within the json file so can you please help me out? its very important

```
void Start()
    {
        playerJson = JsonMapper.ToJson(player);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Player.json", playerJson.ToString());
    }
 public int Xaxis;
    public int Yaxis;
    public int Zaxis;
    public int speed;
 void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Xaxis, Yaxis, Zaxis) * Time.deltaTime *speed);
    }
public class Character
    {
        public int id;
      public int Xaxis;
        public int Yaxis;
        public int Zaxis;
        public int speed;
 public Character(int id, int Xaxis, int Yaxis, int Zaxis, int speed)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.Xaxis = Xaxis;
            this.Yaxis = Yaxis;
            this.Zaxis = Zaxis;
            this.speed = speed;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to export to JSON, you need to serialize them as JSON. Look at Newtonsoft nuget packages which is one of the most popular nuget packages. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is the method that does the serializing.  Then you write the result to a `File`

Comment: how do  i add the result to a file?...i never seen this command before and i cant seem to find something about it could you please tell me in more detail?